# Inefficient CPU usage after applying indexing on DataSerialization Objects

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast

I have a Java web application with Spring and I am using Hazelcast 3.6 to cache lots of data I am retrieving from my Database Server.
Many of my classes have Hazelcast indexing on HZ maps implemented for faster retrieval.

To improve the performance I changed the Serialization implementation from Java's Serializable to DataSerializable which is faster.

As a proof of concept I changed one of the classes and confirmed that the application was faster.
Then, I changed all of my classes/objects/models that were being serialized to DataSerialization.
We used writeObject() to serialize all fields for everyObject because some fields may contain null.

After this bigger change I observed (with a profilerin Eclipse) that the threads responsible for indexing the HazelCast maps were taking all of my CPU usage and the processes never ended.
e.g.
`com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.AddIndexOperation.run(AddIndexOperation.java:73)`

I have also observed the application with all the indexing commented out, and the CPU usage was normal but the application was slower because retrieval without indexed maps is slower

Why does the indexing take so long with DataSerialization as opposed to Serializable?

[UPDATE] DataSerialization Implementation:

```
public class Address implements DataSerializable {
   private String street;
   private Integer zipCode;

   public Address() {}

   //getters setters..

   public void writeData( ObjectDataOutput out ) throws IOException {
      out.writeUTF(street);
      out.writeObject(zipCode);
   }

   public void readData( ObjectDataInput in ) throws IOException {
      street = in.readUTF();
      zipCode = (Integer)in.readObject();
   }
}
```

Implementation of Indexing:

```
@Override
public void addMapIndex(String mapName, String attribute, Boolean ordered) {
    final IMap<?, ?> map = this.getIMapObject(mapName);
    map.addIndex(attribute, ordered);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `DataSerialiable` implementation? Additionally, what do you mean by "threads responsible for indexing the HazelCast maps"? How do you add the indexes to your maps?

Comment: Please see updated thread

Comment: Firstly, you can use `ObjectDataOutput#writeInt` and `ObjectDataInput#readInt` to serialize/deserialize `Integer`s. Additionally, do you have any other fields? If so, do they also implement `DataSerializable`? Lastly, you do not need to recall the indexing more than once per map. You can configure it before you start the cluster, and than the indexes will be updated automatically.